# How create a Quarkus project without Maven Wrapper?

Tags: quarkus

Has a way to scaffold the structure of Quarkus using the Maven Plugin without include the Maven Wrapper?

```
QUARKUS_VERSION=1.13.4.Final \
PROJECT_GROUP_ID=org.acme.app \
PROJECT_ARTIFACT_ID=user \
PROJECT_VERSION=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT; \
  mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:"$QUARKUS_VERSION":create \
    -DprojectGroupId="$PROJECT_GROUP_ID" \
    -DprojectArtifactId="$PROJECT_ARTIFACT_ID" \
    -DprojectVersion="$PROJECT_VERSION" \
    -DclassName="${PROJECT_GROUP_ID}.${PROJECT_ARTIFACT_ID}.MyResource"
```

Answer (score 1):

The Maven Wrapper is **always** included in newly generated Quarkus projects.

Comment: And there's nothing preventing you from deleting it :-)

Comment: Deleting manually works. Perhaps a future parameter can be added.

Comment: I also use the Maven plugin to bootstrap my Quarkus projects, and I wouldn't mind to have a few extra parameters to customize the generated code. Having a `skip.maven.wrapper` parameter, or `skip.docker.files`, or `skip.git`, etc. would be nice.

Comment: Please open an issue asking for this enhancement :)